# Titan - Cassandra: Process entire set of vertices of a given type without running out of memory

Tags: titan

I'm new to Titan and looking for the best way to iterate over the entire set of vertices with a given label without running out of memory.  I come from a strong SQL background so I am still working on switching my way of thinking away from SQL-type thinking.  Let's say I have 1 million profile vertices.  I would like to iterate over each one and perform some type of statistical analysis of the information linked to each profile.  I don't really care how long the entire analysis process takes, but I need to iterate over all of the profiles.  In SQL I would do SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE, using a scroll-sensitive result, fetch the next result, grab and process the info linked to that row, then fetch the next result.  I also don't care if the result is real-time accurate as it is just for gathering general stats, so if a new profile is added during iteration and I miss it, that's ok.

Even if there is a way to grab all the values for a given property, that would probably work too because then I could go through that list and grab each vertex by its ID for example.

Answer (score 2):

I believe titan does lazy loading so you should be able to just iterate over the whole graph:

```
GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> it = graph.traversal().V();
while(it.hasNext()){
    Vertex v = it.next():
    //Do what you want here
}
```

Another option would be to use the [range](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#range-step) step so that you explicitly choose the range of vertices you need. For example:

```
List<Vertex> vertices = graph.traversal().V().range(0, 3).toList();
//Do what you want with your batch of vertices.
```

With regards to getting vertices of a specific type you can query vertices based on their internal properties. For example if you have and internal property `"TYPE"` which defined the type you are interested in. You can query for those vertices by:

```
graph.traversal().V().has("TYPE", "A"); //Gets vertices of type A
graph.traversal().V().has("TYPE", "B"); //Gets vertices of type B
```